# Passing variable to edit form within ActiveAdmin controller

Tags: activeadmin

I'm trying to pass a rather large configuration hash into the data options attribute of an input in my edit form. Instead of sticking the whole thing in the one line I want to tidy up the page by moving the entire hash into a place that makes it more readable. So this is essentially what it looks like now:

```
  controller do
    before_action do
      @froala_options = {
        foobar: 'baz',
        key: Figaro.env.froala_key,
        image_upload_url: upload_image_path,
        image_upload_to_s3: true,
        imageUploadToS3: Rails.application.config.x.aws.s3_upload_defaults
      }
    end
  end


# Edit

  form title: 'New Page' do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :country
      f.input :title
      f.input :slug
      f.input :content, as: :froala_editor, input_html: { data: { options: @froala_options } }
    end
    actions
  end
```

I've tried using:

```
controller do 
  def edit
    # options variable here
  end
end
```

and

```
controller do 
  def edit
    # options variable here
    edit!
  end
end
```

As well as:

```
f.input :content, as: :froala_editor, input_html: { data: { options: proc { @froala_options } } }
```

.. to no avail.

When I inspect what's available with `binding.pry` inside the proc or form block I'm unable to see the @froala_options variable. All there are is methods that deal with the DOM.

I really don't want to begin creating partials to pass things in by using the semantic_form_for (unless I can use that within this AA register page).

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `ActiveAdmin`, when your code executes the `form do..end` block, it gets into the context of `ActiveAdmin::Views::ActiveAdminForm`, which is out of the scope of all instance variables defined inside the controller (like `@froala_options`).

Here you need to know that AA defines **accessors** for those instance variables, which you can get access from inside any view-specific code.

So the solution is really simple: **use Accessors in place of Instance Variables** inside the view context.

```
form title: 'New Page' do |f|
  f.inputs do
    ...
    f.input :content, as: :froala_editor, input_html: { data: { options: froala_options } }
    ...
  end
  actions
end
```

Comment: So, essentially, I just drop the '@' from the instance variable to run the accessor method? I just tried it and this works! Thank you! Is there a place in the documentation I can refer to or is this something you infer by reading the source code?

Comment: I mean exactly that

Comment: `binding.pry` is your friend when you dont get the doc :)

Comment: arg! lol I used binding.pry to inspect the available methods and instance variables and didn't see what I was looking for. Let me check again as it seems I missed something here!

Comment: I suppose you'd have to infer that info by just trying stuff, because I'm looking at the list of methods provided by ActiveAdmin::Views::ActiveAdminForm and it doesn't list the accessor method.

Answer (score -2):

```
ActiveAdmin.register DslPort do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :snmp_profile, as: :select, collection: @dsl_port.snmp_profiles
    end
    f.buttons
  end
end
```

or

```
f.input :snmp_profile, as: :select, collection: DslPort.find(params[:id]).snmp_profiles
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between what you've written and what I've written except that you're passing your variable into a collection option. Where do you define @dsl_port?